# ECM with different representations

Tags: ecm

By construction ECM (Error Correction Model) is represented by the following equation: $$\Delta  Y_{t}=\psi_{1} \Delta X_{t}-(1-\theta)[Y_{t-1}-\alpha-\beta X_{t-1}]+\epsilon_{t}       \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \     (1)$$ 
In the same textbook (Verbeek: *Modern Econometrics*) there is another representation of the ECM model: 
 $$\Delta  Y_{t}=\psi_{1} \Delta X_{t-1}-(1-\theta)[Y_{t-1}-\alpha-\beta X_{t-1}]+\epsilon_{t}  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (2)$$
Taking into consideration that ECM representation derives from the ARDL representation, is it correct to call $(2)$ the ECM representation?

Comment: The classical derivation of VECM is probably from a VAR, not an ARDL, and is represented as $(2)$. Regarding $(1)$, if $X$ is endogenous, estimates of $(1)$ will suffer from endogeneity bias. You can probably also consider $(1)$ a structural form and $(2)$ a reduced form, though I am not sure.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you for your comment. You are right, VEC model derives from VAR model, here I mean only ECM. I have corrected the question, please have a look.

Comment: @RichardHardy In model $(1)$, if $Y_t$ and $X_t$ are cointegrated due to a common dependence on latent variable $Z_t$, will the endogeneity bias you mention be present? Also, presumably model $(1)$ cannot be represented as a VAR or VECM, so would we be restricted to fitting using the two-stage regression approach?